# Autocomplete popup menu with autoindent and hard wrap in insert mode

Tags: autocompletion, indentation, wrapping, plugin-you-complete-me

I have `set autoindent` and `set tw=90` and `set fo=t`. Additionally I have working autocompletion that means when I type one character a popup menu come in. Because of popup menu in some situations, where all these 3 things happen to work together, it gives some very unpleasant random effect.

Example:

I have a line like this that is less than `tw`

```
<some indentation>sdjfl ... sdkf Some
```

Then I add some text and have a cursor in the specified position in insert mode

```
<some indentation>sdjfl ... sdkfslfj <cursor> Some
```

Then I type a character like here

```
<some indentation>sdjfl ... sdkfslfj I Some
```

And vim wraps should wrap and indent me text like this

```
<some indentation>sdjfl ... sdkfslfj 
<some indentation>I<cursor> Some
```

Unfortunately, I have this result

```
<some indentation>sdjfl ... sdkfslfj 
<some indentation>I<cursor>Some
```

Or very often and more unfortunately I have this result

```
<some indentation>sdjfl ... sdkfslfj 
<some indentation>SI<cursor>ome
```

I figured out that when I turn off autocompletion, than
I have many correct result, and sometime this results where it cuts the space before cursor.

Help me to solve this, please?

The options and version of my vim

```
--- Options ---
  autoindent          guioptions=agit     laststatus=0        showbreak=↪       textwidth=90
  background=dark     helplang=en         linebreak           showcmd             timeoutlen=700
  backup              hidden            nomore              noshowmode            ttimeoutlen=900
  comments=b:#,fb:-   history=1000        mouse=a             smartcase           ttyfast
  confirm             hlsearch            number              smartindent         updatetime=800
  copyindent          ignorecase          previewheight=30    softtabstop=2       wildignore=*.pyc
  cursorcolumn        iminsert=0          ruler               splitbelow          wildmenu
  cursorline          incsearch           scroll=26           splitright          window=55
  expandtab         nojoinspaces          scrolloff=3         suffixesadd=.py
  filetype=python     keywordprg=pydoc    shiftwidth=2        syntax=python
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  backupdir=~/Vim/Trash/backup
  cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,!^F,o,O,e
  commentstring=# %s
  directory=~/Vim/Trash/swap
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=utf-8,ucs-bom,latin1,iso-8859-5
  formatoptions=tqcrow
  grepprg=grep -nH --color
  guicursor=n-c-v:block-Cursor-blinkwait1000-blinkon0-blinkoff250,i-ci:ver30-iCursor-blinkwait30000-blinkon200-blinkoff150
  guifont=Powerline Consolas 13
  include=^\s*\(from\|import\)
  includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\.','/','g')
  indentexpr=GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)
  indentkeys=0{,0},:,!^F,o,O,e,<:>,=elif,=except
  makeprg=make -f ~/Documents/Tests/Makefile
  omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
  printoptions=paper:a4
  termencoding=utf-8


VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec  9 2014 17:36:41)
Included patches: 1-488
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version with GTK2-GNOME GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +dialog_con_gui  +insert_expand   +mouse_sgr       +ruby            +vertsplit
+arabic          +diff            +jumplist        -mouse_sysmouse  +scrollbind      +virtualedit
+autocmd         +digraphs        +keymap          +mouse_urxvt     +signs           +visual
+balloon_eval    +dnd             +langmap         +mouse_xterm     +smartindent     +visualextra
+browse          -ebcdic          +libcall         +multi_byte      -sniff           +viminfo
++builtin_terms  +emacs_tags      +linebreak       +multi_lang      +startuptime     +vreplace
+byte_offset     +eval            +lispindent      -mzscheme        +statusline      +wildignore
+cindent         +ex_extra        +listcmds        +netbeans_intg   -sun_workshop    +wildmenu
+clientserver    +extra_search    +localmap        +path_extra      +syntax          +windows
+clipboard       +farsi           +lua             +perl            +tag_binary      +writebackup
+cmdline_compl   +file_in_path    +menu            +persistent_undo +tag_old_static  +X11
+cmdline_hist    +find_in_path    +mksession       +postscript      -tag_any_white   -xfontset
+cmdline_info    +float           +modify_fname    +printer         +tcl             +xim
+comments        +folding         +mouse           +profile         +terminfo        +xsmp_interact
+conceal         -footer          +mouseshape      +python          +termresponse    +xterm_clipboard
+cryptv          +fork()          +mouse_dec       -python3         +textobjects     -xterm_save
+cscope          +gettext         +mouse_gpm       +quickfix        +title           +xpm
+cursorbind      -hangul_input    -mouse_jsbterm   +reltime         +toolbar         
+cursorshape     +iconv           +mouse_netterm   +rightleft       +user_commands
```

Comment: `" Additionally I have working autocompletion"` - as far as I remember Vim doesn't have native autocompletion; it does has generic completion, but is is triggered by some shortcuts (`:help compl-generic`). Are you using some plugin for autocompletion?

Comment: Yes, I use Ycm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the problem just happens when you are using the Ycm plugin, it is certainly something related to that plugin. You should check [plugin documentation](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/blob/master/doc/youcompleteme.txt). In special, the FAQ section reports that some plugins that may cause interference:

```
    9. FAQ |youcompleteme-faq|
   1. I used to be able to 'import vim' in '.ycm_extra_conf.py', but now can't |import-vim|
      :
      :
   18. YCM conflicts with UltiSnips TAB key usage |youcompleteme-ycm-conflicts-with-ultisnips-tab-key-usage|
   19. Why isn't YCM just written in plain VimScript, FFS? |youcompleteme-why-isnt-ycm-just-written-in-plain-vimscript-ffs|
   20. Why does YCM demand such a recent version of Vim? |youcompleteme-why-does-ycm-demand-such-recent-version-of-vim|
   21. I get annoying messages in Vim's status area when I type |youcompleteme-i-get-annoying-messages-in-vims-status-area-when-i-type|
   22. Nasty bugs happen if I have the 'vim-autoclose' plugin installed |vim-sub-autoclose|
```

You could also search the current and closed issues on [the bug tracker](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues). If any of these solves your problem, you should open a new issue there.